# Do something when each loop ends

Tags: javascript, jquery, each

I have a simple each loop like this :

```
 var delay = 0;
$('.triggers a').each(function(){ 
    $(this).delay(delay).animate({
        opacity:1
    },400);
    delay += 50;
});
```

I want do some code after the end of the each loop, is this posible?

How can I do that?

Comment: Can't you just add the code before the close of the .each()?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/promise/ should do

Comment: Do you really mean "when you finish the each loop" or do you mean "when the last animation triggered by the each loop is finished"?

Answer (score 1):

```
var delay = 0;
var length = $('.triggers a').length;
$('.triggers a').each(function(i){
    $(this).delay(delay).animate({
        opacity:1
    },400);
    delay += 50;
    if(length == i+1){ alert('Hello') }
});
```

This should work. You can call a function there and it will launch when the each has finished.

Answer (score 0):

Yes if you want something to run just after the loop...

```
var delay = 0;
$('.triggers a').each(function(){ 
  $(this).delay(delay).animate({
    opacity:1
  },400);
  delay += 50;
});
// more code here
```

But if you want to do something after the animation timers, then you can do this:

```
var delay = 0;
$('.triggers a').each(function(){ 
  $(this).delay(delay).animate({
    opacity:1
  },400, function(){
    // more code here
  });
  delay += 50;
});
```

- read more about [animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by keeping track of how many links are being animated, and how many are done:

```
var delay = 0, links = 0;
$(".triggers a").each(function() {
    $(this).delay(delay).animate({opacity:1},400,function() {
        links--;
        if( links == 0) {doSomething();}
    });
    links++;
    delay += 50;
});
```

This technique is also useful for preloaders (especially image preloders), where you count how many images you have and how many have fired their `onload` events before triggering the "what to do next" function.